# What's the meaning of " He is about as can-do a professional as you will find"

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

I'm not sure about the meaning of this sentence:

> He is about as can-do a professional as you will find.

I know it's a comparative sentence. But does it mean something like "he is the most can-do person we can find on Earth"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the scope doesn't need to be the whole Earth. It means he is as willing and eager (can-do) as the best you will find when you search within some implied set of professionals. That implied set would be in the context of the statement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's perfectly clear now!

Comment: Can-do does not equal capable. It means that you're willing to say "Yes" when asked to do something.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will make a correction in my answer.